# TCL (thermal control language) [printer protocol] references

Tags: printers

I'm working on supporting of the TCL (thermal control protocol, stupid name, its a printer protocol of futurelogic) but i cannot find resources about this protocol, how it is, how it works, nothing, on theirs site i only found this mention http://www.futurelogic-inc.com/trademarks.aspx

any one had worked with it? does any one knows where can i find the data sheet?

Comment: Please don't tag with `tcl`; that's Tool Command Language round here, whatever the trademarks say.

Comment: ok, sorry, i forgot abou the tcl scrippting...

Answer (score 3):

The protocol is documented on their website http://www.futurelogic-inc.com/support/downloads/
If you are targetting the [PSA66ST](http://flgexchange.futurelogic-inc.com/secure2/PSA66ST.pdf) model it supports a number of protocols TCL, which is quite nice for delivering templated tickets and, line printing using the Epson ESC/P protocol.

This is all explained in the protocol document.

Oops, these links are incorrect and only correspond to marketing brochures. You will need to contact Futurelogic for the protocol documents. Probably also need to sign an NDA. Anyway, the information may guide you some more.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, it seems the FutureLogic thermal printers do not support general printing, but only printing using predefined templates stored in the printer's firmware. The basic command structure is a caret `^` followed by a one or two character command code, with arguments delimited using a pipe `|`, and the command ended with another caret `^`. I've been able to reverse-engineer a few commands:

- `^S^` - Printer status
- `^Se^` - Extended printer status
- `^C|x|^` - Clear. Known arguments:

  - `a` - all
  - `j` - jam
- `^P|x|y0|...|yn|^` - Print fields `y0` through `yn` using template `x`.

Data areas are defined in the firmware using a similar command format, command `^D|x|y0|...|yn|^`, and templates are defined from data areas using command `^T|z|x0|...|xn|^`.